# Get the mask of the smallest network possible

Tags: networking

How do I get the mask of the smallest network possible that includes these 2 IP adresses: 87.25.78.79 and 87.110.78.76?

I am new in this area, according to me (it is just a shot in the dark) I need 110-25=85 which is smaller than 2^7=128. So the mask would be /(32-7)=/25?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should exclusive-or the two addresses and count leading zeroes of the result. It's the bit pattern that counts, not the numeric difference.

Comment: I did what You suggested and I get MASK: /9, Please could you confirm the result? Thank You.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct mask. I thought about putting it into the answer, but it's better that you came up with it.